# Proper way to add PublicSubnet/PrivateSubnet in cloudformation json template?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I trying to add VPC in massive Cloudformation json template.
This what I added under "Parameters":

```
       "VpcId" : {
            "Description" : "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
            "Type" : "String"
        }
```

This what I added under "Resources":

```
"VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "172.0.0.0/16",
                "EnableDnsSupport": true,
                "EnableDnsHostnames": true
            }
        },
        "PublicSubnet" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties" : {
            "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "CidrBlock": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetConfig", "Public", "CIDR" ]},
            "Tags": [
              { "Key": "Application", "Value": { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" } },
              { "Key": "Network", "Value": "Public" }
            ]
          }
        },
            "PrivateSubnet" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties" : {
            "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "CidrBlock" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetConfig", "Private", "CIDR" ]},
            "Tags" : [
              { "Key" : "Application", "Value" : { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" } },
              { "Key" : "Network", "Value" : "Private" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

I get error:

> Template validation error: Template error: Mapping named
>   'SubnetConfig' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template.

All that things I found in AWS documentation, and compared with shared examples in github.
What I should put in place Mapping name and where?
Or what I should understand from that error output?
Maybe I missed some additional resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetConfig", "Private", "CIDR" ]`, but in the "Mappings" section of your template, there is no "SubnetConfig".

Take a look in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html). There is an example that shows a "Mappings" section alongside the "Resources" section of the template. In "Mappings" you should declare something like the following:

```
"Mappings" : {
    ...,
    "SubnetConfig" : {
      "Public" : { "CIDR" : "123.456.789.0/24" },
      "Private" : { "CIDR" : "123.456.789.0/24" },
    }
  },
```